# How to copy data with one value changed (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have table 'students' with 'ID, name, surname, <...>, class' columns.

I have students
 1, Michael, Jordan, <...>, A
and 
 2, Dikembe, Mutombo, <...>, B

How can I duplicate the existing table data for all the students with class value set to B, but change the class to C.

IDs have auto_increment enabled.

EDIT: Also, is it possible to do this without explicitly typing all column names?

Comment: Do you want to 1) change the class of the students in the existing table, 2) move them to another table with different a class value, or 3) duplicate the data in the same table but with different class value?

Comment: 3) duplicate the data in the same table but with different class value

Comment: What have you tried already? Best for StackOverflow if you demonstrate some effort in trying to solve so the community can assist fixing what you have tried.

Comment: Your actual question should probably rather be, how do I properly normalize this.

Comment: Sounds about right @CBroe xD

Comment: Have a read OP https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do that:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
(name, username, ..., class)
SELECT name, username, ..., B
FROM tableA
```

---

So if you don't want to type all the columns names you could run the above query but with '*' so you copy all values, then get the ID of the first element and run an update query from that ID on wards to update the class value.

Or have look at something like [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Dialogs/PostDetails.aspx?PostID=667940), which in my opinion sounds a lot more complicated than typing it all out.

Hope you find a solution mate.

Comment: Probably missed my main point in my question. Is there a way to do that without listing all the column names twice?

Comment: @dreifuojantis I don't see you specifying anywhere that you don't want to type all the column names.

Comment: I haven't, it's a mistake on my part. Will edit the question.